# What does 1px by 1px gaussian blurring mean in GIMP?

Tags: image, image-processing, gimp

So I was going through the options in Gaussian blur that are provided in GIMP, one of which is the ability to select the "Blur Radius". From my understanding, the Gaussian filter is created by sampling the Gaussian kernel function for the pixels inside the blurring radius. But that makes no sense if the blurring kernel is 1x1. Can anyone here explain what exactly happens when Gaussian blurring is done on GIMP?

Cheers.

PS: I have asked this question over on [photo.stackexchange.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83940/what-does-1px-by-1px-gaussian-blurring-mean-in-gimp) However, I feel that that this is more of a software question than a photography question, so I'm asking it here.

Comment: This isn't actually a question about programming. To me the photography stackexchange seems like a better fit than here, but if they are not accepting it, then it could go to superuser (being a general software question).

Comment: @thomasrutter it's okay.. I got my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Gaussian kernel is based on the equation `exp(-d²/2σ²)` where `d` is the distance from the center point and σ the "radius". This is a fast decreasing function. The smaller `σ`, the smaller the weight of the surrounding pixels, but it is never zero and in theory the convolution is infinite.

One can estimate that for `σ` smaller than `0.3`, the contribution of the immediate neightbors becomes smaller than `1/256`, hence is completely invisible, but for `σ=1`, it is still `60%`.

Comment: Are you saying that blur radius = 1px is the same as σ=1 ?

Comment: @Roy2511: I don't know about the exact convention used in GIMP, but sigma and radius are certainly proportional. You can check that by blurring a single pixel.

Comment: How do you blur a single pixel? Blurring an image means you soften the edges right? A single pixel, by definition, can not have an edge.

Comment: @Roy2511 Hem a white image with a single black pixel.

Comment: Yes I know that setting \sigma = 1 blurs the image. I used the Tenengrad algorithm to sort of quantify the blur. I was just interested on the relationship between the gaussian kernel and blurring radius. Anyway, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @Roy2511: I don't understand your comment, I did answer that.

Comment: Small typo. I meant that I set **blur radius** = 1 and blurred an image using the Gaussian filter. I then confirmed that the image was actually blurred by using the Tenengrad algorithm.

Comment: @Roy2511: Tenengrad !? This is not a blurring algorithm but a Sobel-based blur assessment method.

Comment: Just a nit:  not all images are limited to 8-bit depth, so your numeric visibility limit really should be "1/(bit-depth)"  .

Comment: Please note that for the development version of GIMP (2.9), bit depth is not limited to 8 bit per pixel - and thus, the smaller than(1/256)  factor is no longer a thrshold value.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: who cares about a radius below 0.3, anyway ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  " 'Tis not for us to judge others..."   :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust .. yes I **confirmed** that the blurring actually occured by using the Tenengrad algorithm. The blur was too small.

Comment: @Roy2511: can you provide a reference to your Tenengrad algorithm ?

Comment: It's pretty simple. You can visit [this link](http://usuario.cicese.mx/~josue/pdf/ArticuloConMario.pdf).

Comment: @Roy2511: that's what I thought. Gaussian blurring isn't used in the Tenengrad algorithm.

Comment: @YvesDaoust .It doesn't matter, the Tenengrad algorithm somewhat approximates the energy of the edges. A sharp edge has more energy and a soft edge has less energy. If a image is blurred by any form of blurring then the Tenengrad operator gives a low value compared to a sharp crisp image. The blur which I got was too small to be seen, so I used the Tenengrad algorithm to confirm that the blurring actually occurred.